# Not able to fit image for variable dimension inside div

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried creating custom classes, assigned max width, max height, width, height, but none of them are working. I have an array of images that I map in React which can be variable size. Hence for each map I have-

```
<div className="slider">
<img src="www..."> // All attributes
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
    .slider {
    width:700px;
    height:487px;
    display: block;
}
```

I have tried max-width:100%, max-width:100%, same with px, object-fit, etc. Nothing seems to work, for large images it overflows, for small images, the div after it comes at top and is un-clickable.

Comment: Have You tried to add the Display properties even to images? Like display : block? Can you please provide the css used for the images?

Comment: This is the only code, nothing for images

Comment: I think that you should try to add some css to images to make them fit into the Div father. And make sizes based on father sizes. Or make the Father sizes "auto" to base them on children.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? If i would have known CSS, wouldn't have asked the question. Sorry, but I'm very new and unable to debug.

Comment: Ok basically when you put a Tag inside another one, like : <tag1><tag2/></tag1> there will be a hierarchy where tag1 is the father of tag2. When you write css you can use different type of mesurement (%,rem,em,cm,px) and based on the one you use it will adjust the item with Father size, or with Page size. Just check out on the net to understand the mesurement differences. Anyway, you gotta work on some css for the children to make it smaller like the father sizes, or edit the father css to make it adjust himself based on the children size. When I'll get home I can send you a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super simple example of what you are trying to accomplish as I promised in comments. (Sorry for being that late)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    
        .container:
        {
            width:100%;
            display: flex;
            border : 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .slider
        {
            float : left;
            width:400px;
            height:300px;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-right : 20px;
        }
        
        img
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slider">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--G-sdBgNR--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/z7jcryloxjedsztssw39.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533450718592-29d45635f0a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8anBnfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tested it : You should see 3 images all same size (slider sized).
I also made a JSFiddle for you :
[JSFiddle Online Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zd021kvg/3/)